# Remotely interacting with php console application

Tags: php

Im working on a php **console** application that is best to run on single instance, **not made to run on browser** in stateless way and constantly restarting. However, this console application should interact and receive commands from Client Browser remotely.

For example:

- The client makes a request from browser to login to his account
- The request is forwarded to the console application
- The console app waits until user types his credentials and submits.
- After user is logged in, the console app is still running the same instance and waits for commands from client.

I have expirmented in a couple solutions but im not sure what is the correct way to achieve this.

Comment: you will need to scope this a little tighter, its probably going to be closed as to broad.

Comment: PHP is not designed for such a task. It will be hard to implement a server app handling multiple clients, however, it is actually not impossible. **What is the operating system?**

Comment: Assuming a Linux server, see [socket functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) and to be able to serve multiple clients you should prefork the single-treaded process via [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) You need to manage multiple child processes on your own and even fork new ones on demand when there is heavy load.

Comment: As mentioned above, the question is far too broad to be answered on StackOverflow. Try your luck with the given hints and come back with a specific question when running into an issue on implementation.

Comment: **Recommendation:** If this is not only an educational project to see how it could be done, you are much better adviced to use **node.js** which is designed to handle multiple requests in parallel on an event-driven framework.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks for your answer, using sockets might work. anyway  i choose php because im more familiar with the language but now im thinking to switch to node.js.

Comment: If you have the choice, you really should. There are also code bases for C++ already managing multiple connections in parallel. I consider using that for bigger projects I want to distribute as native code applications. However, scripting in node.js needs only very few lines of code and you have a listening full server process online. PHP is singlethreaded and child processes need to be managed from the scratch. Only one connection can be handled at a time. You need to spawn childs and pass requests to them to handle those in order to continue listening on the port with the main proc.